# Python & Pandas: Convert series of datetime-values to consecutive day-indices

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, days

I have a Series `a` in pandas:

```
>>> type(a)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

consisting of `datetime64[ns]` values:

```
>>> print a
0   2000-11-01
...
10   2000-11-04
11   2000-11-05
...
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

I want to convert this to a integer-series describing the day, whereas the first value (*2000-11-01*) should have the index 1. Currently I'm doing it using:

```
b = (a-a.min()).astype('timedelta64[D]').astype(int)+1
```

So I first substract the minimal datetime64 (`a-a.min()`), resulting in a `timedelta64[ns]`, which I first need to convert to days (`timedelta64[D]`) and then to integer-values. The direct conversion from `timedelta64[ns]` to `int` is not possible.

I'm wondering if there's a better way of doing this. 
For my current Series-object containing a little over 800k rows, this takes already 4secs Oo

---

### EDIT

The Series contains datetimes for several months. Example data with resulting integer values as a consecutive day-series. In this case, *2000-11-03* is the oldest date, thus getting the index 1 as described above. The datetimes *2000-11-05* is not present (would have been index 3), but *2000-11-06* still should be assigned *4* asit is the fourth day starting from *2000-11-03*:

```
2000-01-03 -> 1
2000-01-04 -> 2
2000-01-06 -> 4
...
2000-01-31 -> 29
2000-02-01 -> 30
2000-02-02 -> 31
2000-02-04 -> 33
...
```

Comment: Do you have an entry for every day? If so, the answer becomes trivial: Your (integer) index is already what you seek.... additional information on the series may give an idea about possible tricks

Comment: @FooBar: Thanks, I added example data and the values supposed to be assigned as result of the conversation. I think the day as integer itself is not sufficient to what I want to do.

Comment: what version pandas/numpy?

Comment: numpy 1.8.1, pandas 0.14, python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:18) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]

Comment: Just to clarify: The solution above works fine, just concerned about its performance...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The performance issue was recently fixed [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/7342). This will be in 0.14.1 (coming soon, dev binaries for windows are posted [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-build/dev/), the current posted are slightly out of date and don't include this fix, check back soon).

FYI docs for timedelta conversions are [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#time-deltas-conversions)

```
In [1]: s = Series(pd.date_range('20000101',periods=10000).tolist() * 80)
```

0.14.0

```
In [3]: %timeit (s-s.min()).astype('timedelta64[D]').astype(int)+1
1 loops, best of 3: 2.9 s per loop
```

0.14.1

```
In [12]: %timeit (s-s.min()).astype('timedelta64[D]').astype(int)+1
10 loops, best of 3: 24.7 ms per loop
```

Comment: wow okay, didn't know that this is a bug. I got to admit I don't quite understand what's the bug itself actually reading your linked page, but I guess that's not really necessary - hoping for the release soon :-) But the question remains: A direct conversion is not possible to maybe even increase performance more? As for now, there are two consecutive conversions done (to timedelta64[**D**] and from there to **int**...? So at least my solution above is the right way to do it?

Comment: ``timedelta64`` are kept internally as nanoseconds so the ``astype('timedelta64[D]')`` returns a ``float64`` series of the days (you CAN have fractional days, FYI). You don't need to convert to int unless you need int. The time in my example for the to-int conversion is about ``1.5ms`` so YMMV.

Comment: I want the days to become the x-values when plotting some random values against the single days, but yes, for that I'd probably better simply use the float values. For now I thought it'd be cleaner to use int as perfectly round/precise values (as my days should never be fractional), but there shouldn't be no problem using float, or do you see a stumbling block?

Comment: I added a link to the docs, their is a slight difference between what you are doing and ``(s-s.min())/np.timedelta64(1,'D')`` (numpy truncates); virtually same perf though.

Comment: Ok thanks yet again, and which of the versions would you prefer? Probably the one you (and me) posted, i.e. the version with `.astype('timedelta64[D]')`? Just argueing intuitively, a type-casting should probably be also faster compared to the division by `np.timedelta64(1,'D')` right?

Comment: they are virtually the same, except that the division truncates rathern than gives an exact answer.